# How to add a value to a collection in other bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, portlet

I have an application context and several subcontext (one for each portlet) in a Spring MVC Web Application.

In this context I have a properties bean, with general configuration parameters. How can I add some properties to this bean from the other contexts? 
I know I can use something like a MethodInvoker but, doesn't exists a more robust method?

Comment: Are you using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or `<context:property-placeholder` mechanism to load the properties in the bean ?

Comment: @Santosh, no, I'm using a simple `PropertiesFactoryBean`